# rotate triangle to match other half of square

Tags: javascript, matrix, 3d, rotation, three.js

Alright,

so i have a 3D world consisting of tiles which consist of 2 triangles. Now when i hover on one of these triangles i can get the 3 vertices and normal of it etc.

What i want to achieve is ,based on the vertices of the hovered blue triangle, to rotate it around the hypotenuse (the middle black line) or do something else? So that i can get the matching point (as show in the picture). Now i have the 4 vertices of the square and thus i can draw a square above it which overlays the 2 triangles.

I'm using threejs so i guess with a simple matrix rotation i should be able to do this, but i fail.

[image: picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this if you know the `Vector3` lets say `v` of the black line like this:

```
var axis = v.normalize();

var theta = Math.PI;

var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis( axis, theta );
```

and then apply this matrix to your triangle.

You can get vector `v` by doing `v = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors( a, b );` where a and b are points on the line.

In this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wilt/tuejqpay/1/)** you can see that it works. Be aware that `.sub( a, b )` changed to `subVectors( a, b )` in the newer Three.js library.

Comment: Thanks, but vector3 of a line? is that the same as a vertex point of the blue triangle on that line? Or how do i find it

Comment: I added it to my answer

Comment: I don't seem to get it, you give me a matrix4 and i only have 3 vertices of the triangle, so a matrix3, so how do i apply it to each other?

Comment: Don't you have a geometry? Then you can do `geometry.applyMatrix(matrix);`

Comment: Hmmm since i have a planegeometry, i get the 3 vertices of the triangle and create a new geometry for it (the red in below picture) this works all fine, but when applying the rotation you say to the blue, i get the following red triangle: http://imgur.com/7bTQLsj

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I had rotated my plane around the x-axis and totally forgot about this, its works now thank you :)